# SQL Three Table Join and sort

Tags: sql, mysql

So, I have countries, regions and groups.

```
countries
|cid|name|
regions
|rid|name|cid|
groups
|gid|name|phone|time|rid|
```

So how can I select each group with its country and region in order:

eg.

```
|cname|rname|gname|phone|time|
|Australia|nsw|test|1111|whatever|
|Australia|nsw|test2|110|whatever|
|Australia|vic|test3|100|whatever|
|England|London|tes4|010|whatever|
```

Comment: Steven, You might find some of the responses to your questions a little, shall we say, *impatient*. This happens soon after an SO user was recently suspended after asking nearly 500 questions, without showing the least attempt to do some prior research or to learn from the answers. Well ... others may describe it differently, but this is a community website and some effort on the part of the original poster will go a long way toward eliciting answers.

Comment: @steven: Just FYI, the relevant section on sorting of the MySQL manual can be found at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html.  I think James' answer below gives you what you need for joining your tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT c.name, r.name, g.name 
FROM groups g INNER JOIN regions r ON(r.rid=g.rid) 
    INNER JOIN countries c ON(c.cid=r.cid) 
ORDER BY c.name, r.name, g.name;
```

This should get you most of the way that you want to go.

I didn't know what you wanted to order by.

Comment: see how it goes Country, state, group in a-z order.

Comment: something like "SELECT * FROM Google WHERE query = 'sql order by clause'"

Comment: I just edited it to answer Steven's order by inquiry. Granted he probably figured it out by now and should have deleted his comments.